# Possível conflito entre script

Tags: jquery, ajax

Bom pessoal, eu uso basicamente 4 scripts no meu projeto.

Eu tenho duas paginas, uma onde as postagens são listadas e outra onde visualiza as postagens.
No modelo atual de navegação, ao clicar em cima de qualquer postagens listada o usuário e enviado para a pagina com a postagem completa, nada de diferente e tudo dando certo.

A questão que estou tentando mudar o modo de visualização das postagens. No novo modo ao clicar sobre alguma postagem listada se abre um Lightbox e dentro desse Lightbox é carregada via Ajax a pagina com as informações. Até aqui estaria tudo dando certo se não fosse por um detalhe.

O detalhe é que as vezes algumas postagens podem ter videos. No modelo antigo de visualização das postagens os vídeos rodavam normalmente, só que nessa tentativa de novo modelo os vídeos referentes as postagens não fazem nada, é como se estivessem travados. Acho que algum dos scripts estão entrando em conflito. Eis os scripts ::

Script do Lightbox

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.lightbox').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.background, .box').animate({'opacity':'.8'}, 0);
    $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 0);
    $('.background, .box').css('display', 'block');
});
$('.close').click(function(){
$('.background, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 0, function(){
$('.background, .box').css('display', 'none');
});          
});
$('.background').click(function(){
$('.background, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 0, function(){
$('.background, .box').css('display', 'none');
});          
});
});
```

Script do Carregamento ajax

```
function GetXMLHttp() {
if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else {
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
return xmlHttp;
}

var xmlRequest = GetXMLHttp();

function abrirPag(valor){
var url = valor;

xmlRequest.open("GET",url,true);
xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = mudancaEstado;
xmlRequest.send(null);

if (xmlRequest.readyState == 1) {
document.getElementById("conteudo_mostrar").innerHTML = "<img src='loader.gif'>";
}

return url;
}

function mudancaEstado(){
if (xmlRequest.readyState == 4){
document.getElementById("conteudo_mostrar").innerHTML = xmlRequest.responseText;
}
}
```

Script usado para realizar funções sobre o video como play, pausar e demais

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer({
success: function(media, node, player) {
var events = ['loadstart', 'play','pause', 'ended'];
for (var i=0, il=events.length; i<il; i++) {
var eventName = events[i];
media.addEventListener(events[i], function(e) {
$('#output').append( $('<div>' + e.type + '</div>') );
});
}
}
});
```

Teria mais 1 script de configuração do player do vídeo. Tal script pode ser vizualizado no link https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/blob/master/build/mediaelement-and-player.js

Tomei a liberdade também de tirar print para vocês verem como ficam a execução do scripts no lightbox e sem ser no lightbox

Sem Lightbox :: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZt5K.jpg
Com Lightbox :: [http://imgur.com/xv0E3yL](https://imgur.com/xv0E3yL)

Fiz um teste e acrescentei o player de vídeo direto dentro do Lightbox e não gerou nenhum conflito, então o problema pode estar no carregamento Ajax porém não sei aonde

Comment: Não deu nenhum erro no console quando você fez via ajax? Sugiro verificar algumas coisas: 1) a página antiga tinha algum script no head? lembre-se que o conteúdo carregado via ajax não tem html nem head (não tem mesmo, né? se tiver, é um erro); 2) Existem elementos com o mesmo id no conteúdo carregado dinamicamente e na página principal? 3) Poste em algum lugar (ex. pastebin) o código completo tanto da página principal quanto de uma das páginas com vídeo que não funciona. Está difícil imaginar o que pode estar acontecendo só com as informações postadas.

Comment: Posso estar enganado, mas não é exatamente um conflito. Acontece que scripts carregados por scripts não funcionam mesmo. Experimenta fazer a requisição AJAX pela prórpia jQuery ($.ajax, $.get...). De repente, alguma coisa no próprio framework leva isso em consideração e soluciona por você. Se não der certo, carregue o script do video junto com o HTMl que dispara o lightbox e invoque o *mediaelementplayer* no callback de sucesso da requisição AJAX. Outra possibilidade seria usar jQuery.on() para anexar os eventos dinamicamente.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto o que voce falo é verdade, fiz alguns testes e realmente os scripts nao estao sendo carregados... A unica parte do codigo que esta sendo carregada é aquela ao qual não é script

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Isso é novidade pra mim! Você tem alguma referência que eu possa consultar? Eu achava que qualquer coisa retornada via Ajax, em formato texto, que fosse atribuída a um elemento via `innerHTML` fosse ser indiscriminadamente aceita. Em que parte eu me enganei?

Comment: @mgibsonbr JS não é exatamente minha praia, por isso eu comento meio que pisando em ovos, justamente por não ter certeza absoluta. Porém, anos atrás, haviam artigos, inclusive no blog do Micox (acho que todo mundo conhece o Micox) com scripts que visavam contornar essa limitação, fazendo um eval() dos scripts presentes na resposta de uma requisição AJAX. Não sei como as coisas são hoje, se a jQuery leva isso em consideração e "corrige" automaticamente ou não. Seja como for, isso já era errado antes e imagino que ainda seja uma má prática.

Comment: Não é o método correto mas fiz aqui uma gambiarra. Eu mudei a pagina que era carregada a postagem, por uma pagina que tem um frame, e esse frame carrega a pagina que tem a postagem. Funciona como reflexos, onde um carrega o conteúdo da outra, afinal o frame carrega a pagina com o scripts, assim deixa o conteúdo já pronto, e o Lightbox carrega o frame, e o frame já não tem mais scripts, assim o Ajax carrega todas informações sem problemas. Como eu disse, é uma gambiarra, mas resolveu o problema dos scripts que não carregam scripts. OBS :: Sou pessimo com JS

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Entendi. De todo modo, você está certo, fiz um teste no jsFiddle que comprova isso: http://jsfiddle.net/7sKMa/ Pelo que sei, se você cria um elemento `script` usando `document.createElement` e adiciona esse script no `head`, ele executa. Meu senso comum achava que também era o caso ao se incluir `<script></script>` no `innerHTML` de um elemento qualquer (ou do próprio `head` ou `body`), mas vejo que estava enganado.

Comment: ivanveloso Gambiarra ou não, é uma solução, se quiser postar como resposta fique à vontade. @BrunoAugusto o mesmo vale pras coisas que você comentou, afinal elas foram chave na solução do problema.

Comment: Quando você carrega um modal com elementos dependentes, você vai ter que carregar os arquivos na modal que contém o video, pois os botões de ação ainda não estão criados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resposta a seguir tem como objetivo estender a discussão inicial nos comentários da pergunta.

---

De acordo com a [Especificação do W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#document-response-entity-body):

> Scripts na árvore do documento resultante não serão executados, recursos referenciados não serão carregados e nenhum XSLT será aplicado.

Para muitos programadores, AJAX é a cura pro câncer de suas Aplicações. Não vou entrar no mérito de que isso é extremamente errado, de que JavaScript obstrusivo é uma péssima prática, de que a Aplicação tem de funcionar o máximo possível sem JavaScript e etc. MAS, essa limitação impede que uma Aplicação rica, fracione seus scripts carregando-os sob demanda.

Imagine um Painel Administrativo que funciona perfeitamente sem JS, mas que com ele o Administrador tem um controle mais rápido e uma experiência de controle aprimorada.

Além de carregar frameworks e plugins básicos comuns à todas ou muitas páginas, não faz sentido, por exemplo, carregar aquele pequeno arquivo que configura ou prepara recursos presentes apenas num formulário de cadastro de Clientes quando estamos visualizando, não sei, a seção de Relatórios de Desempenho, certo?

Sim, esses pequenos arquivos são inofensivos num Painel Administrativo o qual é acessado simultaneamente por poucas pessoas, mas a limitação "imposta" pelo W3C não se restringe à esse cenário.

Deve haver um meio mais inteligente de contornar essa limitação. Para a solução proposta e descrita abaixo estarei assumindo que a requisição AJAX tenha sido completada com sucesso, haja vista tudo acontecer em seu *callback*.

Estarei usando como demonstração o [jQuery TimeAgo](https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago) unicamente por se tratar de um script o qual cumpre uma tarefa simples. E também porque foi um dos primeiros retornados na listagem do GitHub :P

**timeago.html**

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://timeago.yarp.com/jquery.timeago.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</script>

</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

Não temos absolutamente nada mais além do que a inclusão do script externo a partir do site oficial já que não consegui carregá-lo pelo GitHub (nem mesmo pelo RAW).

Para testar, nesse arquivo mesmo poderíamos adicionar ao HTML:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-12-17T09:24:17Z">December 17, 2011</abbr>
```

E o JS correspondente no [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$("abbr.timeago").timeago();
```

E teríamos a saída **3 years ago**

Pois bem, voltando ao foco principal, temos o segundo arquivo onde a requisição AJAX será feita:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#loadData').click(function(event) {

            $.ajax({

                url: 'timeago.html',

                success: function( response, status, xhr ) {

                    $("abbr.timeago").timeago();
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>

</head>

<body>
<p>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="loadData">
    Load jQuery TimeAGO
</a>

<p>
    <abbr class="timeago" title="2011-12-17T09:24:17Z">December 17, 2011</abbr>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Teoricamente, ao clicar no link o `<abbr>` seria substituído pela expressão **3 years ago**. Em teoria até mulher é perfeita, mas não adianta pensar no `<body>` se elas se importam como `<head>` (essa piada é um horror)

Verificando o console vemos o erro correspondente ao método da jQuery TimeAgo não existir por não ter sido carregada.

Comecemos a jornada rumo à solução por localizar os scripts no corpo da requisição retornado:

```
var scripts = $( response ).filter( 'script' );
```

Depois vamos iterar essas informações e carregá-los no DOM atual. Existem técnicas que criam elementos novos `<script>` e setam os *src* e levam em conta particularidades as quais dado meu relativamente pouco contato com JS não vou nem mencionar.

A jQuery nos oferece o [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) que nada mais é do que um atalho para um [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) tendo o **dataType** devidamente configurado para **script**.

Nós poderiamos iterar essas informações e fazer N chamadas à [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) mas isso nos traz um problema. [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) só trabalha com requisições assíncronas, ou seja, assim que ela termina, ela já é retornada de imediato o que nos impede de utilizar os recursos dos scripts carregados em escopos diferentes de seu próprio *callback* de sucesso.

Pareceu confuso mas é simples. Usar [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) nos impede de fazer isso:

```
$.getScript( 'myexternalScriptFile.js' );
someFunctionfromTheFileAbove();
```

Permitindo apenas isso:

```
$.getScript( 'myexternalScriptFile.js', function() {

    someFunctionfromTheFileAbove()
})
```

Não parece ser um problema, mas isso por consequencia impede que um segundo [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) utilize algum recurso presente no script carregado pelo primeiro.

Felizmente a [jQuery 1.5](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/01/31/jquery-15-released/) implementou os [Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) para todas as requisições AJAX.

Por ser uma requisição assíncrona, logicamente ela precisaria de um *callback* porém, com [Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), temos uma enorme vantagem através do [jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) o qual podemos expandir, carregando múltiplos arquivos mas usando um único *callback*:

```
$.when( $.getScript( 'scriptOne.js' ), $.getScript('scriptTwo.js') ).done( function () {
  sometgingFromScriptOne();
  somethingFromScriptTwo();
});
```

Como consequência, todos os recursos, de todos os scripts carregados estariam acessíveis

Já se pode ter uma noção de como a solução final ficaria, isto é, iterar e invocar [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) dentro de [jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) informando um único *callback* para [deferred.done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/):

```
jQuery.each( scripts, function( index, value ) {

    $.when( $.getScript( value.src ) ).done( doneCallback );

});
```

Mas, temos mais um probleminha. Aqui nós estamos confiando no valor da propriedade **src** das informações retornadas quando filtramos o corpo da Requisição buscando pelas tags `<script>`. Sim, eu repeti tudo isso pra chamar sua atenção. ^_^

Rotinas *inline*, isto é, as que não vêm de uma origem externa, obviamente não possuem um atributo **src** (pelo menos não um preenchido) e, por isso, não são resolvidas por [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

Pra esses casos, temos o bom e velho, e muitas vezes considerado um vilão perverso, [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). Uma simples condição e solucionamos o problema:

```
jQuery.each( scripts, function( index, value ) {

    if( value.src == "" ) {

        eval( value.text );

    } else {

        $.when( $.getScript( value.src ) ).done( doneCallback );
    }
});
```

Perfeito... Se aquilo que possa ter sido avaliado por [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) não puder em hipótese alguma ser utilizado por alguma coisa carregada por [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) >.<

Mais uma vez a jQuery nos salva través de [jQuery.globalEval()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.globaleval/) que faz o mesmo que o [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) tradicional, exceto que em escopo global.

Não preciso nem dizer que se [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) pode ser perigoso, um [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) global pode ser ainda mais, certo?

O script final, do arquivo inteiro dessa vez:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#loadData').click(function(event) {

            $.ajax({

                url: 'timeago.html',

                success: function( response, status, xhr ) {

                    var scripts = $( response ).filter( 'script' );

                    jQuery.each( scripts, function( index, value ) {

                        if( value.src == "" ) {

                            jQuery.globalEval( value.text );

                        } else {

                            $.when( $.getScript( value.src ) ).done( doneCallback );
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });


    function doneCallback() {

        $("abbr.timeago").timeago();

        alert( someInlineScriptvar );
    }

</script>

</head>

<body>
<p>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="loadData">
    Load jQuery TimeAGO
</a>

<p>
    <abbr class="timeago" title="2011-12-17T09:24:17Z">December 17, 2011</abbr>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Deixe-me fazer uma pequena consideração final.

Em nosso *doneCallback()* temos um alert() para uma variável não descrita em nenhuma parte do texto. As vezes eu tenho desses péssimo costume ao redigir um texto e acabo e escrevendo as coisas numa ordem diferente daquela que eu deveria.

Essa variável surgiu de um teste feito logo que finalizei com a solução com [jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) e me ocorreu o fato de scripts *inline* não terem uma propriedade **src** preenchida.

No arquivo **timeago.html** eu criei uma variável simples, com um valor também simples logo depois de chamar o script externo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var someInlineScriptvar = 'Foo';

</script>
```

Assim pude ter certeza de que a solução funcionaria nos dois principais cenários, pra não dizer únicos.

Fontes utilizadas na solução:

- ["jQuery .load() call doesn't execute javascript in loaded html file"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7330106) (Chamada à jQuery.load() não executa JavaScript presente no arquivo carregado)
- ["Can I use jquery getScript() without a callback?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8026693) (Posso usar jQuery .getScript() sem um callback?)

Comment: Foi uma resposta longa e um pouco maçante, mas eu espero ter me feito entender bem, já que não sou muito chegado em JavaScript. Qualquer erro, seja de conteúdo ou de sintaxe, quem melhor entender, por favor, fique à vontade para uma edição.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.posts a').live('click',function(){

$('#conteudo.mostrar').load($(this).attr('href'));

return false;

});
});
```

isso dai resolve todos os problemas

Comment: Ok, mas o método `live` não está mais disponível nas versões atuais do jQuery. Para delegar o tratamento de evento hoje em dia, é preciso usar `.on` em algum ancestral que já exista no DOM, passando o seletor como segundo parâmetro.