# Por quê meu codigo Jquery não funciona em elementos carregados com .load(), como carrega-los?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Qual a maneira correta de carregar meus scripts jQuery junto com o .load().

Fiz desta maneira mas queria outra solução que funcionasse com todas as atualizações que ocorrerem com o formulário, como remover de produtos, alterar de quantidade do carrinho e etc:

```
// Adição ao Carrinho com retorno de plugins Jquery

$('#Carrinho').submit(function () {
    var $this = jQuery(this),
        dados = $this.serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'json',
        url: $this.attr('action'),
        data: dados,
        complete: function (update) {
            if ($(".list-inline button").hasClass("active")) {
                $("#cart-header").load("https://127.0.0.1/ #cart-header-container", function () {

                    // Estou atualizando meu carrinho, mas os demais scripts de remoção de produtos 
                    //ao carrinho, e alteração de quantidades precisam vir junto com está função, se o 
                    //usuários adicionar 10 produtos ao carrinho teria de repetir 10 vezes esse, e o 
                    //codigo ficaria muito longo, e não acredito ser a técnica correta.

                    // Abre - Fecha Sacola  
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#cart-right-nav").click(function () {
                            $("#cart-header").slideToggle("slow");
                        });
                    });
                    // Fim Abre - Fecha Sacola  
                });
                $("#cart-head-loader").fadeOut(1000);
            } else {
                $("#buy-btn").css("display", "block")
                $(".added-to-cart").css("display", "none");
            }
        },
        error: function (erro) {
            alert("Não adicionou a sacola.");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: O que exatamente não funciona? O que esta acontecendo, e o que deveria acontecer? Qual trecho de código não esta sendo executado?

Comment: Funciona, só que é o seguinte,  no .load() eu chamo um script para funcionar com o conteúdo que foi carregado, só esse conteúdo carregado vai precisar de outro .load() com outro script para funcionar, assim meu código ficará extenso demais, queria uma solução que carregasse meu código, toda vez que o .load() fosse usado. Tentei colocar o código dentro dos elementos que são carregados, mas não funciona, o .load() não traz meu código junto. @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira

Comment: Não é exatamente uma duplicata, mas muito provavelmente [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26592/250) resolveria seu problema pois ao que parece você está tentando executar um script em uma página que foi carregada por AJAX o que, **nativamente**, é impossível.

Comment: Excelente resposta @BrunoAugusto, me parece a solução. vou tentar implementa-la no código e ver o que da.Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obrigado novamente ao Bruno Augusto, que praticamente solucionou meu problema !

```
              $.getScript('script-carrinho.js');
```

Consegui resolver apenas fazendo uma chamada do arquivo 'script-carrinho.js', 
Através do $.getScript(), dentro do callback do 'complete' , assim o script necessário para o funcionamento desta função fica carregado todas vez que ela for executada.

```
$('#Carrinho').submit(function () {
    var $this = jQuery(this),
        dados = $this.serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'json',
        url: $this.attr('action'),
        data: dados,
        complete: function (update) {
            if ($(".list-inline button").hasClass("active")) {
                $("#cart-header").load("https://127.0.0.1/ #cart-header-container", function () {


                  $.getScript('script-carrinho.js');

                    // Consegui resolver apenas fazendo uma chamada do arquivo 'script-carrinho.js', 
                   // Através do $.getScript(), assim o script necessário para o funcionamento desta,
                  // função fica carregado.


                    // Abre - Fecha Sacola   --- Este script também entrou no arvuio 'script-carrinho.js'
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#cart-right-nav").click(function () {
                            $("#cart-header").slideToggle("slow");
                        });
                    });
                  // Fim Abre - Fecha Sacola --- Este script também entrou no arvuio 'script-carrinho.js'


                });
                $("#cart-head-loader").fadeOut(1000);
            } else {
                $("#buy-btn").css("display", "block")
                $(".added-to-cart").css("display", "none");
            }
        },
        error: function (erro) {
            alert("Não adicionou a sacola.");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```