# Códigos jQuery para javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou tendo problemas, Javascript é muito confuso para mim, vejamos que tenho uma funcao que realiza tudo isso em jQuery

```
$(".message-form-content").attr('style', ' '); // Esvazia o style da div
$("#load-content").html(success); // Preenche com o sucess da funcao
$("#imageForm").reset(); // Reseta o formulario
$("#post9999999999").val(''); // da empty na textarea
$("#post9999999999").focus(); // Focaliza na textarea
$("#queued-files").html("0"); // Poe valor 0
$(".selected-files").fadeOut(600); // Desaparece em fadeout
$("div.timeago").timeago(); // Renove
return true;
```

Preciso transformar tudo isso em Javascript, pois no arquivo em que a função é puxada nao pode existir jQuery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok... cá vai, porque o Natal está aí à porta :)

> #### $(".message-form-content").attr('style', ' ');

```
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll(".message-form-content");
for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++){
    elementos[i].style = '';
}
```

> #### $("#load-content").html(success);

```
document.getElementById('load-content').innerHTML = success;
```

> #### $("#imageForm").reset();

```
document.getElementById('imageForm').reset();
```

> #### $("#post9999999999").val('');

```
document.getElementById('post9999999999').value = '';
```

#### $("#post9999999999").focus();

```
document.getElementById('post9999999999').focus();
```

> #### $("#queued-files").html("0");

```
document.getElementById('queued-files').innerHTML = "0";
// repare que assim como tinha é string, pode tamber fazer .innerHTML = "0" para ter Type Number
```

> #### $(".selected-files").fadeOut(600);

**Nota:** pode (e deve!) fazer isto com CSS, já há respostas sobre isso aqui no SOpt.
Mas em JS acho que não há, exmeplo live: http://jsfiddle.net/0sxqnnc0/.

```
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('.selected-files');
for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    elementos[i].style.opacity = 1;
    fade(elementos[i], 600);
}

function fade(el, duracao) {
    if ((el.style.opacity -= 40 / duracao) < 0) el.style.display = "none";
    else setTimeout(function () {
        fade(el, duracao);
    }, 40);
}
```

> #### $("div.timeago").timeago();

Esta tem de fazer uma pergunta à parte :) Tem de explicar melhor que plugin é e que função faz.

Comment: [Nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26592/250), coincidentemente, o script usado para demonstrar a solução é o jQuery TimeAgo, que converte uma data para a notação de "Há X dias" ou "X minutos atrás".

Comment: @BrunoAugusto boa! Eu vejo que já tinha dado `+1` nessa resposta... Se alguém mais ler isto pode ir dar `+1` lá por mim :)

Comment: @Sergio Obrigado..

Comment: EDIT: para esvaziar o `style` optei por trocar o codigo para: `document.getElementById('message-form-content').removeAttribute("style");`

Answer (score 3):

Amigo, acho que ninguém vai converter tudo isso pra você.

Muitas das coisas que o jQuery faz é, na verdade, muito simples de se fazer apenas com Javascript.

Coloco aqui algumas páginas para você pesquisar:

- youmightnotneedjquery.com
- github.com/jquery/jquery (código fonte do jQuery)
- github.com/mootools/mootools-core (código fonte do MooTools)

Eu particularmente gosto de vasculhar o código fonte de certas bibliotecas, e muitas vezes me surpreendo com quão simples é fazer certas coisas.

Comment: `+1` por colocar o link http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ !